# How do I change bottom tabs background color

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, tabs

I am working on `Xamarin.Forms`. I have *bottom tabs* in my android project. Tabs are showing default background color something light gray. I need to change tabs background color to my preferred color. But I am not able to do so.
The code below I am using

**MainPage.xaml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MyTabbedPage 
 xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:edTheSIS"    
 x:Class="edTheSIS.ParentDashboard">
<local:DairyTabPage  Icon="icon1"></local:DairyTabPage>
<local:MykidTabPage  Icon="icon2" ></local:MykidTab>
<local:EventsPage   Icon="icon3"></local:Events>
<local:AboutPage    Icon="icon4"></local:About>
</MyTabbedPage>
```

**MyTabbedPage.cs file**

```
public class MyTabbedPage : Xamarin.Forms.TabbedPage
{
    public MyTabbedPage()
    {
        On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().SetToolbarPlacement(ToolbarPlacement.Bottom);
    }
}
```

Output I am getting screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try this out.

```
On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().SetToolbarPlacement(ToolbarPlacement.Bottom);

On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().SetBarSelectedItemColor(Color.White); --> to change the selected color tabitem

On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().SetBarItemColor(Color.Gray); --> Gray is the default color but you can also change this to any color.
```

Example :

```
On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().SetBarItemColor(Color.Green);
```

If you are using FormsAppCompatActivity, you can use

```
app:tabIndicatorColor="#FF3300" <!-- Set indicator color here, sets it to red-->
```

**Edit**

You'll need to create a custom renderer.

Check [this](https://github.com/smetlov/XamarinFormsAndroidBottomMenu/tree/master/CustomBottomMenu) sample on github.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is not changing background color at all. Its changing Icons color & selected item color.

Comment: This is tab indicator color not background color  `app:tabIndicatorColor `. Moreover bottom tabs are not using layouts from native android project.

Comment: Yes, I get it now. You will need to create a custom renderers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BarBackgroundColor property to change Toolbar background color as said in [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/tabbed-page#create-a-tabbedpage)

Example:
BarBackgroundColor = Color.LightGray;

[image]